# Didn't get promised raise due to unsufficient projects

Tags: communication, salary, germany, raise, lying

I started my new job as a software engineer in a bank in January 2019. According to our collective agreement (Tarifvertrag), my position is rated as wage group (Tarifgruppe) 8.
During the job interviews I was told, that it's common in this company to start one wage group below (7) and in 1 year I will be automatically "promoted" into my actual wage group (8). This has been confirmed by my direct manager and the manager of our HR. Unfortunately, it wasn't written in my contract.

During the year I had regular meetings with my manager. Every time he confirmed, that he is happy with my work.

---

In January 2020, after 1 year in my new job, I still got my "old" salary. After confronting my manager, he also seemed surprised: "Maybe we should stop saying to our new applicants, that they will be promoted automatically after 1 year."
He also talked to the IT manager, what didn't help either.

I talked to the manager of our HR. He said: "Maybe you just haven't met all the required criteria?".
The employee organization (Betriebsrat) told me, that it's a common problem. The "automatic promotion" is a lie that is always being told to new applicants. He can't help me.

Since my manager couldn't help me either, I arranged a meeting directly with the IT manager. I showed him the list of my projects during my first year. He seemed surprised and wasn't aware that I did "so much". He promised to show this list to the CEO asap and was confident about my raise.

For over 8 weeks I was trying to get another appointment with him to receive an answer. Finally my manager spoke to the IT manager and told me, the CEO had a look at my projects, they were not sufficient for wage group 8, so there won't be a raise. He will decide again next January.

---

I love my job and my colleagues, I don't want to leave.
But I was lied to and nobody even denies it! I was performing well during my first year, but apparently it was not "sufficient enough". My manager couldn't tell me, what exactly I can "improve" for the raise. He is not helpful in that case.
Also I was surprised that the IT manager seemed to avoid me for 8 weeks.

I'm very disappointed by my bosses behavior and losing my motivation.
BTW: A colleague from my department has similar problems, so I don't think, boss A has a personal problem with me.

How to deal with that situation?
I want to get a definite answer about why I didn't get the promised raise and what exactly to do in order to get it.
On the other hand I'm getting the feeling, that I'm starting to annoy my bosses already.

Comment: So, what is the question? Because between "I do not want to leave" you ask more for career or life advice than a concrete work related question. I would be out the moment the betriebsrat confirms that it was regularly commited fraud.

Comment: Am I having a Deja Vu moment here or was question asked and closed within the past few weeks?

Comment: @Steve I think you're right that it was asked within the past few weeks. I can't remember what happened with it, though.

Comment: You already got an answer: They lie to new applicants to make the job look better than it really is. Look for a new job an next time, get everything that is relevant to you in writing!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you were lied to and now nobody wants to help you. Not your direct manager, not their boss, not HR and not the Betriebsrat.

Since it was probably just a verbal lie, there is nothing you can do.

You can get another job, which should not be a problem later this year or you can accept it for what it is and be happy with whatever group 7 gives you.

Personally, I'd have a hard time trusting *anything* those bunch of scumbags say ever again. But it's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

What has happened has happened. They conned you and you fell for it.

As far as the past goes you can walk away or stay, you seem to be committed to staying so that’s the decision made and dwelling on it will do no good.

For the future you want an agreement about what exactly they want you to do to get the result you want. Go to your boss and make it clear how important the salary issue is to you and ask to be allocated a set of projects that will allow the CEO to give you what you want. Get that list of projects, exceed expectations in completing them and in January ask for the agreed reward.

If you do this and they shaft you again you know where you stand and can make the stay or go decision with solid facts about the culture you are in.

If you stay my rule of thumb is that if they shaft you three times without negative results for them they will identify you as someone they can shaft forever without consequences. Be careful if you choose to live your life in this condition.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get a definite answer about why I didn't get the promised
>   raise and what exactly to do in order to get it.

Sounds like you did indeed get your answer. As you wrote: "the CEO had a look at my projects, they were not sufficient for wage group 8, so there won't be a raise. He will decide again next January."

It's understandable that you are unhappy. But you have your answer - work on more sufficient projects and wait until next January. Seems like you can either do that, or find a new job and leave this one.

Comment: The OP indeed got an answer, either the CEO of the bank (often banks in germany are local) and said no, or the IT manager lied and said the CEO said no neither are good and its just carrot dangling.